# How to find a specific cell and replace by a text

Tags: vba, excel

On an active range selection, how to find only the cells that contains "0" and "#N/A" - and replace it by text "NA" and change the font color to "red".

Here is the macro I am using to "convert formulas to absolute values " and "to find empty cells to put text "NA".

```
sub XConvertToValues()
   Dim MyRange As Range
   Dim MyCell As Range
   Set MyRange = Selection
   For Each MyCell In MyRange
       If MyCell.HasFormula Then
           MyCell.Formula = MyCell.Value
       End If
       If IsEmpty(MyCell.Value) = True Then
           MyCell.Value = "NA"
       End If
   Next MyCell
   End Sub
```

Comment: how many columns can Selection have?

Comment: IS that a request for a VBA code? What have you done so far and where is your specific problem? Maybe you try to use the recorder and use the search function.

Comment: I have just updated my post. i should have been more descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** after OP's clarification about data format

use `Replace()` and `AutoFilter()` method of `Range` object

```
Sub XConvertToValues()
    With Selection
        .Value = .Value '<--| convert all formulas to their values
        .Replace What:="#N/A", replacement:="NA", LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:="0", replacement:="NA", LookAt:=xlWhole
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "NA") > 0 Then
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="NA"
            .Resize(IIf(.Cells(1) = "NA", .Rows.count, .Rows.count - 1)).Offset(IIf(.Cells(1) = "NA", 0, 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Font.ColorIndex = 3
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - This didnt work either. I will check again and circle back.

Comment: What "didn't work!". Be more explicit. And add examples of a "before" and "after" scenarios of your data

Comment: This works for only the cells with "#N/A". Didn’t work if the cell value is "0"

Comment: could you please select one of cells with _uncatchable_ "0" and tell me what do you read in the formula bar?

Comment: I have the column formatted as "Currency" - here is a set of Data - **$1.47
$1.57
$2.04
$0.00
#N/A
$0.00
$1.47
$1.43
$4.50
$0.00
$0.00
$9.55
$1.37**

The Formula bar shows only "0"

Comment: Thank you so much @user3598756 . I have something of this sort recorded macro which also does the changing font thing. The problem with the recorded macro is that if i change anything on the windows replace function pop out - let say if i change the color to blue there for a different search and i come back to run this macro - the color reamin blue! This code works - but could you add something to make the replaced text word as RED and doesnt change even after you mess us with the replace pop out? Hope it makes sense

Comment: Awesome - this works! Thanks a TON! you are amazing @user3598756

Answer (score 0):

**edit**

Now as you have provided more info, this can be done like:

Try this

```
Sub ConvertToValues()

Dim R As Long
k = Sheet1.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row   '-> total rows in column A

For R = 1 To k
 If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(R, 2)) = True Or Sheet1.Cells(R, 2) = "#NA" Or Sheet1.Cells(R, 2) = "0" Then
 Sheet1.Cells(R, 2).Value = "NA"
 Sheet1.Cells(R, 2).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End If
Next R
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ambrish - I am really a noob here. Could you see my VBA code and help me if you could find the cells that contains "0" and "#N/A" - and replace it by text "NA" and change the font color to "red".

Comment: Thanks Again Ambrish. I have tried this already and this does not seem to work. I have not been able to figure out why - we are missing something here.

Comment: Note that `Cells(R, 1)` can also be written as `Cells(R, "A")` (something that I only realised recently thanks to some great answers on SO)

Comment: Your `MyCell.Value = "#NA"` (which is missing a `/`) will probably need to be `MyCell.Text = "#N/A"` so that it picks up error values of `#N/A` and not just cells containing the string `"#N/A"` (or perhaps `MyCell.Value = CVErr(xlErrNA)` if the OP doesn't want to treat the string value in the same way as the error value)

Comment: I tried changing to `"#N/A"`
but we still have a problem here
`MyCell.Value = "#NA" Or
  MyCell.Value= "0"  Then`

Comment: See my edited answer and let me know if it works @RajKharibam

Comment: Ambrish - your example is exactly what i want - Now how to make this work on a Specific Range of **selection**. And I want to add this right after my Code `MyCell.Formula = MyCell.Value
   End If` on my post. (i,e - After i convert the selection to only values ) @AmbrishPathak

Comment: Also please see `If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(R, 2)) = True Or Sheet1.Cells(R, 2) = "#NA" Or Sheet1.Cells(R, 2) = "0" Then` If i change "#NA" to "#N/A" and run it with some data - this doesnt seem to work. gives an error. the new code will be `If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(R, 2)) = True Or Sheet1.Cells(R, 2) = "#N/A" Or Sheet1.Cells(R, 2) = "0" Then`

Answer (score 0):

i'm beginner too , this what can i make and maybe it will help you , you can just put number of cells you want to change or rewrite the code with FOR EACH

```
Dim i As Integer

On Error Resume Next

For i = 1 To 20

cells.Find(What:="0", MatchCase:=False_, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NA"
With Selection.Font
    .Color = -16776961
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

cells.Find(What:="#N/A", MatchCase:=False_, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NA"
With Selection.Font
    .Color = -16776961
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With  
Next i
```

Comment: This only works for the text "#N/A"- Provided we change `With Selection.Font
    .Color = -16776961
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With` to `With ActiveCell.Font
    .Color = -16776961
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With`

this doesnt work for the number "0"